# r function to change values

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(
  year = c(2018, 2019, 2020, 2021))
```

I would like the data to look like this:

```
d2 <- tibble(
  year = c(201718, 201819, 201920, 202021))
```

I have the following function:

```
date_change = function(x, n) {
 x+199600
}
```

Then if I apply it to the data:

```
date_change(d$year)
```

I get:

```
 [1] 201618 201619 201620 201621
```

This isn't quite what I want though. Does anyone have any idea how to do this using a function?

I know I can just replace the value manually but I need a function to be able to apply the rule to a large data set.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe just use `mutate`? What is your expected output?

Comment: The values you are adding is not getting the correct output.  You may need a different number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit maths:

```
d <- tibble(year = c(2018, 2019, 2020, 2021))

d %>%
  mutate(year = floor(year / 100) * 10000 + (year %% 1000 - 1) * 100 + year %% 100)

# year
# <dbl>
#   1 201718
# 2 201819
# 3 201920
# 4 202021
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution, working in your special case :

```
paste0(d$year-1, d$year-2000)
[1] "201718" "201819" "201920" "202021"
```